# SKReceiptReceiptRequest - On the simulator, only the request:didFailWithError method is called. I am not able to make my app obtain a sandbox receipt

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase

In a iOS app I am developing, I would like to perform some receipt validation, especially for in-app purchase. I am not able to set up a sandbox testing environment to test my app in the simulator. I am trying to use SKReceiptRefreshRequest but the only delegate method that gets called is request:didFailWithError, with no error description. It works fine on the devices. Is it impossible to test in the simulator ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a real device to make in-app purchases on iOS